# Immediately add eventListener to page TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a project where I want an event listener to be on the page when the page loads to wait for a message (a message from an external source will be sent instantly to this page when this page loads, so it has to be able to listen for it). Is there a way to do this in a TypeScript module? or does it have to be external of the module?

Possibly something like:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass{
        constructor { ... }
        public addEventListeners() : void { ... }
        ...
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var class: MyClass = new MyClass();
    class.addEventListeners();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify module name and use something else from `class` which is reserved word:

```
window.onload = () => {
    var classInstance = new MyModule.MyClass();
    classInstance.addEventListeners();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload` will work fine. Recommend checking `document.readyState` to make sure that it is not already completed (needed for lazy loading a page).

Take a look at Jquery Ready [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/9d820fbde6d89bc7a06e2704be61cf6c0b4d6e3c/src/core/ready.js)